# Nuxt.js vuex store not persisted

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, state, vuex, store

I've got some strange issues with my Nuxt.js Setup.
Some States in Store arent persistent, everytime I load another view, they went back to the default value.

*pages/test.vue*

```html
<template>
  <section class="section">
    <b-container>
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols=12>
          <b-button @click="setTest" variant="dark">test</b-button> | {{this.$store.state.test}} |
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  methods: {
    setTest() {
      this.$store.commit("setTest")
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

*store/index.js*

```js
export const state = () => ({
  test: "test"
})

export const mutations = {
  setTest: (state) => state.test = 'Hello'
}
```

Testscenario is to hit the "test"-button who call the method with mutation-commit "setTest" which set the state to "Hello". Currently it works fine, but if I changed the view or reload the page, the state is set to default "test".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is totally legit that the Vuex store is "reset" if you F5 the page. What do you mean by "changed the view" ? vue-router or modifying the URL by yourself ?

Comment: Hey @kissu :-)

I "change the view" by just clicking on by navbar-links, e.g.: 
<b-dropdown-item href="/profile">{{ $t("my_profile") }}</b-dropdown-item>

So is it realy reloading? I use the common build-in things from nuxt.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, so the behavior is totally logic. Vuex/Pinia are not supposed to be persistent.

For any persistence on the front-end, you need either:

- cookies
- localStorage
- pass it in the URL (query params)
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)
- get the data back from making a call to a backend

If you are using Vuex or Pinia, there are also packages that you could use to get an easier time (to sync your store into something persistent automatically).

Some of the packages here may be useful: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#persistence

For pinia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73863929/8816585

---

If you reload your page with an F5, all your JS will be wiped and loaded again. Hence, no **state** will be kept since it will be a brand new page. When working with frontend frameworks, you cannot expect it to just work after a page refresh.

Same go when you do follow an `href`, it is an actual *real* navigation. What you need to do, is to use a `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>` component, with something like `to="/profile"` to let VueJS move to this URL.

[NuxtLink](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtlink-component) is a Nuxt.js component and essentially a component on top of `<router-link></router-link>`, which is [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/).

TLDR: you cannot use things like `window.location.href`, nor `<a href="..."`. You may use the given components by either Nuxt (`nuxt-link`) or Vue's router (`router-link`), if you're using VueJS only.

Giving a read to the Vue router's documentation may be a good start to understand things a bit more !

---

If you're using `nuxt/auth`, give a try to that one: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/storage/#universal-storage

Comment: I can also suggest [Vuex Persisted State plugin](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate#readme).