# Vuex / Filter: preserve input value on navigation

Tags: input, filter, nuxt.js, vuex

Does anyone know how can I select an item from my `filteredResults` array and display it as the input's value? Furthermore, I need that on page navigation this input value to remain the same if I refresh or navigate back and forth through the pages.

```
<template>
  <div class="search-input relative">
    <label class="block">
      <span class="text-gray-700 font-bold">{{ label }}</span>
      <input
          type="search"
          class="mt-1 p-2 block min-w-full border-0 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 bg-transparent border-b-2 border-blue-500"
          autocomplete="off"
          :placeholder="placeholder"
          v-model.trim="keyword"
          @click="resetAirport"
      >
    </label>
    <ul v-if="filteredResults != null" class="mt-2 absolute shadow-md rounded-lg">
        <li v-for="result in filteredResults" :key="result.id" class="p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100" @click="selectAirport(result)">
          <NuxtLink to="/" class="block">
            {{ result.icao }}, {{ result.iata }} {{ result.name }}
          </NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <NuxtLink :to="`/airport/LRAR`" class="text-gray-300 mt-2 text-xs text-right">Details</NuxtLink>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {},
    data() {
        return {
            keyword: '',
        }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
            getAirports: 'getAirports'
      }),
      filteredResults() {
        if (this.keyword.length < 3) return null
  
        return this.getAirports.filter(item => { 
          if (!item.icao) return false

          return item.icao
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase())
        })
      },
    },
    methods: {
      selectAirport: function(airport) {
        this.addAirport({airport: airport, type: this.type})
        this.keyword = `${airport.icao}, ${airport.iata} (${airport.city}) / ${airport.name}`
      },
      resetAirport: function() {
        if (this.keyword != null) {
          this.removeAirport(this.type)
          this.keyword = ''
        }
      },
      ...mapActions([
        'addAirport',
        'removeAirport'
      ])
    },
    props: {
      label: String,
      placeholder: String,
      type: String,
    }
})
</script>
```

Here is my store:

```
export const state = () => ({
    airports: [],
    pairing: {
        departure: null,
        arrival: null
    },
    loading: false
})

export const mutations = {
    SET_AIRPORTS(state, payload) {
        state.airports = payload
    },
    SET_AIRPORT(state, { airport, type }) {
        state.pairing[type] = airport
    },
    CLEAR_AIRPORT(state, type) {
        state.pairing[type] = null
    }
}

export const actions = {
    addAirport({ commit }, { airport, type }) {
        commit('SET_AIRPORT', { airport, type })
    },
      removeAirport({ commit }, type) {
        commit('CLEAR_AIRPORT', type)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you need some persistency. What did you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe give a read to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585

Comment: @kissu, so far I thought that upon clicking one of the items within the `filteredResults()`, the relevant `pairing.departure` or `pairing.arrival` state within my store will take the value of the clicked item based on the `type` prop. Furthermore, once the state get's updated the value of the keyword in my component shall become the value of the state of either `pairing.departure` or `pairing.arrival`.

This was my view on achieving the persistency, however I never managed to implement it.

Do you think I can achieve this with Vuex store? based on the snippet above?

Thanks for the link!

Comment: Your Vuex store is not something that will persist because it's just runtime JavaScript. As explained in my previous link, you need some kind of persistency to survive the reload of the page. If you refresh a SPA, all the content is wiped since it's front-end only.

Comment: I might have explained myself in the wrong way...what I want to do is that when a user clicks a link, defined using NuxtLink, and navigates to another page within the SPA but then decides to go back to where the input is, then I want the input to remain populated with the data from Vuex. In this case, do I still need to arrange the persistency with localStorage? given the user never actually leaves the SPA.

Comment: For this, `keep-alive` may be helpful. Otherwise, make a conditional on the input checking if a value is present in the store and populate it if it is.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a snippet with the best approach (in your opinion) on this? I would be keen to have this implemented in the most optimal way as this input field lays at the core of developing the rest of the SPA.