# nuxt auth - loggedIn:false and user:null

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, laravel-8

pls can someone help me, i use  Nuxt js and laravel. The  user logged in  successfully but the loggedIn is still false and and user is null,  i have tried everything what else can i do pls help me.
I think the error is from the state

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'laravel-nuxt-api',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
   '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
  ],
  auth:{
   strategies: {
    laravelSanctum: {
      provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', 
     
      user: {
                property:false,
            }, 
      endpoints:{
          login:{url:"/api/login",method:"post"},
          logout:{url:"/api/logout",method:"post"},
          allrecords:{url:"/api/allrecords",method:"post"},
          user: {url: "/api/user",method:"get", property: false }
        },
        
       }
      
      },
      redirect:{
        login:'/auth/login',
        logout:'/',
        home:'/'
      }
    },
  axios:{
    baseURL:"http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

login.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <a href="#" @click="login()">Login</a>

    </div>

</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                form:{
                    email: 'ade@gmail.com',
                     password: '12345'
                }
            }
        },
        methods:{
               async login(){
           this.errors='';
           try {
               const res = await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
          data:this.form})
               if(res){
                await this.$auth.setUser(res.data.user )
                console.log(res);
               }
            //    console.log(res);
           } catch (error) {
               console.log(error)

           }


        }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "laravel-nuxt-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1637745161.ea53f98",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5"
  }
}
```

it's working fine in post man please help me

[image: VIEW IMAGE]

[image: (Vuex State) User: is still Null]

Comment: You maybe need `setUser` here since you set `user.property` to false.

Comment: Please Where should i put the setUser?

Comment: Just after `loginWith`.

Comment: This what i did and it still getting false

Comment: Hey, please do not post code in comments. Rather edit your question.

Comment: Please what else can i do?

Comment: As said just above: edit your question instead.

Comment: Ohh! Pls i am sorry about that. I have edited my question now.
I added the setUser to it still yet it still returning user as a Null

Comment: Try to use the `async/await` syntax rather than `.then`. And set both one after the other. With `await this.$auth.loginWith(...)` and then `await this.$auth.setUser({ email: 'cool@gmail.com' })`.

Comment: I have done that and the user is still Null but i can get user data when i consoled showing it worked but the user is still Null.
Pls check the Image i attached on my question

Comment: You should use the content of `res` for your `setUser` method. Or maybe try `await this.$auth.setUser({ ...this.form })`.

Comment: I have tried both yet same thing, please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe add `autoFetch: false,` to your `user` object in your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks it worked, but i got only user email and password only, can't get other user data info

Comment: I'm thinking it might be from here : await this.$auth.setUser({  data:this.form }).

Comment: It should work if you pass all the fields from `res` to `setUser` I guess. At the end, if it doesn't work, feel free to create another Vuex store for this specific purpose. At the end, this module is used only for auth, so maybe it's not supported (I think it does tho).

Comment: Pls What can i put in there to get all user info as it consoled in the browser apart from only username and password i got

Comment: `this.$auth.setUser(res.data.user)` is not working here?

Comment: Yes! you're right i want add in res into setUser but am getting an error pls how can i add it to setUser

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Thanks so much it worked fine now, But if i refresh my browser the whole data disappears and loggedIn is still set to false , pls what can i do is there any work around to fix this?

Comment: You need to set [persistency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585) and probably use a middleware here.

Comment: I have not done that before, pls any reference ?
Can you help me out pls?

Comment: For persistency, you already have a link above (previous comment) as for the middleware, a good start may be [this documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware). You can also check YouTube, make some searches here (on SO) or give a few glances at some of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+middleware), there is maybe something related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the following in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    laravelSanctum: {
      user: {
        property: false,
        autoFetch: false,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

and calling

```js
await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', ...)
await this.$auth.setUser({ ... }) // your cool JS object representing the user
```

should do the job here.