# How can I set up a similar structure to local storage in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, frontend, local-storage, vuejs3

I am working on a project with vuejs3. I need to save some data somewhere globally and call another page. I was using local storage for this, but this doesn't feel right and it gets harder to manage as the project grows.

at user login

```
lookie.set("userType", "student")
```

at another component

```
lookie.get("userType")
```

For example, there are two user types as student and teacher in the project, I keep their user type in the local storage at the user login, and I do not display some components if the user type in the local storage is student.
I used the state structure, but it didn't work for me because it reverts to its default value when the page is refreshed. What kind of structure do you think I should set up?

Comment: Use State Management library like Vuex or Pinia and override the getter and setter with local storage data manipulation methods

Comment: Since you're on Vue3, use Pinia: https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Comment: FWIW, both Vuex and Pinia have persistence plugins

Comment: yes i used it but when i refresh the page the state reverts to its old default value @kissu

Comment: You of course need some way to persist it, so localStorage is a good way. Conclusion, use `localStorage` + `Pinia` to have both a global state + persistency. More details available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585

Comment: @SerkanGün You can use state management to get the data from the store with in a application and local storage to get it whenever user refresh the page as on refresh state will get reset and initialize again.

Comment: As kissu pointed out, you need both advantages: persistence (which is provided by localstorage) and flexibility in structuring data (provided by pinia). The solution is to save the state of Pinia in localStorage (as a string) and to load it on page load, if it's found. Pinia comes with a [persistence plugin](https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate) which handles it for you with minimal setup. You can configure which state props are saved or which are not, etc...