# How can I use vuex-persistedstate on Nuxt for only specific stores?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is the library: https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate.
I created the following plugin file for Nuxt.

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({ store }) => {
  createPersistedState()(store)
}
```

The problem is I am not sure how I can exlude certain stores since this persists all the stores.

Answer (score 0):

The repo you're sharing is archived as of today so you should probably pass on it and switch to Pinia.

There are 2 packages doing that with Pinia:

- https://prazdevs.github.io/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/guide/advanced.html#multiple-persistences-per-store
- https://seb-l.github.io/pinia-plugin-persist/advanced/custom-key.html

Otherwise, a homemade solution may be needed but `vuex-persistedstate` will not allow you to select a store as you initially wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default ({ store }) => {
  createPersistedState({
    paths: ["myData", "someOtherData"],
  })(store);
};
```

You can reference state you want to persist as a value to `paths`.
If you use vuex modules its `"moduleName.myData"`.