# Doesn't see data from store after reboot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

in App.vue I get user data (if he is authorized)

```
onMounted(  async () => {
   await init();
});
```

added the initialization function to the useAuthComposables file

```
import { authService } from '@/shared/services/v1/auth.service';
import { useAuthStore } from '@/store/auth';

export default function () {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  const init = async () => {
    const [error, data] = await authService.getAuthUser();

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      authStore.setUser(data);
      authStore.setToken(true);
    }
  };

  return {
    init
  };
}
```

and the store itself useAuthStore

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('authStore', {
  state: () => ({
    user: null,
    isLoggedIn: false
  }),
  actions: {
    setUser(data: any) {
      this.user = data;
    },
    setToken(isAuth: boolean) {
      this.isLoggedIn = isAuth;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getUser(state: any) {
      return state.user;
    }
  }
});
```

when I reload the page (f5) in the route does not see the side

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next): Promise<any> => {
  const authStore =  useAuthStore();

  console.log('beforeEach',authStore.getUser);

  if (!authStore.isLoggedIn) {
    next({ name: 'Login' });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

but when I just follow the links, it displays a stor

Comment: When you refresh a page, you are loading a new page - so, the store data is no longer - use some form of browser storage (localStorage, cookies, etc) - I think there's pinia plugins for that

Comment: Yep, as told above: you should look into persistency. Give a read to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585

Comment: i load user data in app.vue

Comment: It's not relevant as of where you load it if you don't persist it. Maybe you do, but we don't know what your composable is doing here.

Comment: when updating in the app, I get a request for a back and saves it in the store

Comment: Maybe you missed the 2nd sentence of the link that I've sent you. But pinia is not persisted by default. Doesn't matter if it's there or not, you need extra work on top of that.