# how to open new tab in inertiaJs and vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

I want to open a file on a new tab but my inertia props are lost,

my approach on opening new tab is this

```js
window.location.href = "/view/"+props.document.type+"/"+props.document.id, "_blank"
```

but the my inertia props are lost. It only returns a blank html page

Comment: Sorry i just forgot to add return on my server

Answer (score 1):

Update: there was a missing `return` in OP's code.

---

If you open a new tab, you will have your SPA nuked. The idea is to persist it with something like cookies or alike. Give a try to that answer for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585

VueJS by default has no way to persist any state out of the box (it's client side code).