# Login with storege browser

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3, vuex4

I'm having trouble finding something that I can show me a way to follow my project, in it I have a login page with store pinia, when I f5 all my data that was in the pinia and reset, this causes me a big problem because all time a user gives f5 to my pinia store will lose his information such as the jwt token , username and password , in this I have some functions that check if these data are matched and valid to let users log in , so every time the browser is updated will lose the data consequently the login too, I was looking at the browser's localstore it would be a good idea, could someone just give me a light on how I would do this
my store image when I login
[image: my store image when I login],
my store image when I refresh the browser
[image: my store image when I refresh the browser]

Comment: Did you gave a try to that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585 There are a lot of plugins for persistency already.

Comment: Some code as of what you tried + your setup is highly welcome too. Some images are not enough effort-wise.

Comment: so instead of using the pinia store I should put this data in the browser store?

Comment: Pinia is a Vue's global state store. Persistency is something totally different. One is not exclusive to the other. There are some packages that a doing the heavy lifting for you and combining Pinia + persistency, as explained in my answer.