# vite-plugin-pages - Route with params/props (Not in URL)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

What structure should be used to generate a route that accepts a param(s).

Eg.

i have pages/verify.vue which produces a verify route.
However when i use

```js
router.push({ name: 'verify', params: { phone: '+18383' } })
```

the route is changed to the verify page but the params are discarded because they were not preset on the route.The warning below is thrown:

```
[Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "phone" when navigating.
```

What to do to solve this issue without without switching to manual route definitions?
NOTE: I prefer not to have the param values in the url!

**Way forward:**
It seems file system routes have no way of allowing props through except through the URL. I will be moving on with Pinia (State Management) as a workaround for this task.

Comment: What is the rest of your config (router) and what do you want exactly?

Comment: The vite-plugin-pages generates the routes based of the names of the files in the pages directory. It also allows for dynamic url routes based on some conventions

Comment: @kissu, I need to be able to parse some params to the verify page.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, you should have `pages/verify/[phone].vue`.

Comment: @kissu That would mean the url will be like `localhost:8000/verify/+184923.` And that is not something i want

Comment: You cannot send a param, without a dynamic point in your URL. You cannot go skateboarding without an actual skateboard, same here. Either use just the numbers without the `+` or use an URL query, use some cookies/localStorage, a Vuex store, or alike. Several approaches here even tho I'm not sure why the param one I've suggested is not fine with you.

Comment: Vue router allows you to send a param when pushing a route by specifying the param name in the route creation. However, because vite-plugin-pages auto generates the routes, i dont have such control. The one you suggested is not ideal because not every data should be displayed in the URL. 

I appreciate your help though

Comment: What vue-router is doing and what vite-plugin-pages (Nuxt or a lot of other frameworks tbh) is the way to go if you want a route param. If you don't want a route param, I've already listed a few solutions in my previous comment aka pretty [much this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872372/8816585) and query params.

Answer (score 0):

OP will be using Pinia for the given use case, as a workaround.

More alternatives are available here: [vite-plugin-pages - Route with params/props (Not in URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74919891/vite-plugin-pages-route-with-params-props-not-in-url#comment132215610_74919891)